# New file for every Swift class

Tags: swift

I create new files for every classes in my Swift project. For example a file for `FirstTableViewController` class and second file for `FirstTableViewCell` class.

But in some tutorials I've seen these two classes in one file like

```
import UIKit 

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {}

class FirstTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {}
```

Can someone tell me which way is preferred and why?

Comment: its upto you that you manage these classes in one file or not... if your class code is huge then its better that you make separate files also if your code is short enough to maintain in just one file then its better to maintain that in only one file

Comment: This is not specific to iOS.

Comment: "But in some tutorials I've seen these two classes in one file ..." and in another in three or even more files. I personally suggest you to divide your code so that some logically related code is written in one file and to name the file in the same way. For example "StringUtilitiesExtension.swift" will consist of your specific String extensions etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only comes in picture when you want share the file with multiple Modules.

Suppose you have extension in your app like today extension or watch app extension.

Suppose You have class named A in A.Swift, class B and C in B.Swift file.
And you want to share only Class A and Class B to your extension.
In this case Your class C will be automatically shared with Your extension because it will be there in B.swift.

Because You can share Files between extension or target modules, not the Classes directly.